# Webview: Cannot read property 'style' of null + unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, android, webview

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    String url = "http://www.google.com";



    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {}
            });
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red'; " +  
                    "})()");  
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() document.write('hola que tal');})()");
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('toggleMenu').item(0).style.display='none';})()");
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {window.alert('hola');})()");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //item(0);
        }
    });
```

mWebView.loadUrl(url);

The web loads, the toast its working, but the injected javascripts are not working...
I tried almost everything i founded on google and i cant make this work, i am doidn something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could append a `HTMLScriptElement` to the `head` tag:

```
HtmlElement head = view.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = view.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement el = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
el.text =  @"document.body.style.color = 'red';
             document.querySelector('.toggleMenu').style.display = 'none';";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```